# PHP Pointers behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, pointers

While working on a project which checks the if Laravel models are related to each other I noticed some (weird?) pointer behavior going on with PHP. Below is a minimal example to reproduce what I found.

```
<?php

$arr = ['a', 'b', ['c']];


foreach($arr as &$letter) {
    if (!is_array($letter)) {
        $letter = [$letter];    
    }
}

dump($arr);

foreach($arr as $letter) {
    dump($arr);
}

function dump(...$dump) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($dump);
    echo '</pre>';  
}
```

At first I expected the dumps in this response to all return the same data:

```
[ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ]
```

But that is not what happened, I got the following responses:

```
[ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ]
[ ['a'], ['b'], ['a'] ]
[ ['a'], ['b'], ['b'] ]
[ ['a'], ['b'], ['b'] ]
```

A running example can be found [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/yyLvVEqHajVO7SeA).

Why do the pointers act this way? How can I update `$letter` in the first loop without having to do `$arr[$key] = $letter`?

---

*Edit: As people seem to be misunderstanding why there is a second `foreach` loop, this is to show that the array is changing without being reassigned*

Comment: @B001ᛦ, this is a minimal example. My actual work does not only have a single element

Comment: What did you expect by outputting the array during foreach ?

Comment: @AymDev As stated in the question, I would not expect the second `foreach` loop to show a different output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)

// Without an `unset($value)`, `$value` is still a reference to the last item: `$arr[3]`

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // $arr[3] will be updated with each value from $arr...
    echo "{$key} => {$value} ";
    print_r($arr);
}
// ...until ultimately the second-to-last value is copied onto the last value

/* output:
   0 => 2 Array ( [0] => 2, [1] => 4, [2] => 6, [3] => 2 )
   1 => 4 Array ( [0] => 2, [1] => 4, [2] => 6, [3] => 4 )
   2 => 6 Array ( [0] => 2, [1] => 4, [2] => 6, [3] => 6 )
   3 => 6 Array ( [0] => 2, [1] => 4, [2] => 6, [3] => 6 ) */
```

Comment: Interesting! So it's not related to pointers, but that the `value` does not get destroyed after the loop completes

Comment: It's related to variables scopes. `foreach` doesn't have his own scope. As a dirty explanation: `$value` has script/file scope in this case. And this variable available for unsing after loop. 

(More about scopes)[http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php]

Answer (score 1):

First of all: PHP doesn't have pointers, it has references. See [What references are](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php) and [What references are not](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php) for more information.

The reason this happens is that `$letter` after the foreach loop still holds a reference to the last element of your array (which is `[c]`). So in your second loop, you're overriding not only `$letter` while looping but also the reference it points to.

To solve the problem you need to `unset($letter)` after your first loop:

```
$arr = ['a', 'b', ['c']];

foreach($arr as &$letter) {
    if (!is_array($letter)) {
        $letter = [$letter];    
    }
}
unset($letter);   // this is important

dump($arr);

foreach($arr as $letter) {
    dump($arr);
}

function dump(...$dump) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($dump);
    echo '</pre>';  
}
```